# How do I link BitTorrent Sync Pro on my second computer?

Tags: bittorrent-sync

I have a laptop and a desktop. I want BTSync to work on both with one identity. It is working on my laptop.

Everytime I start Bittorrent Sync on my desktop, it asks me for a new identity. I am afraid if I try to activate my license on this new identity, it will revoke it on my actual identity.

How do I simply pair BTSync to my existing identity?

Comment: What does your license agreement say? Maybe you need to buy another license?

Comment: Really? I didn't think so, for just syncing two computers. In fact, if I didn't own a phone, that would be the only point of a license- to sync two computers.

Comment: I don't know, that why I suggested you read the license ;)

Comment: Read the license, it is indeed within the license.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the exact same problem. In previous versions Sync asked whether to create an identity or to link to an existing one. In recent versions Sync forces you to create a new identity.

Comment: I did, but it's weird. Solution below

Answer (score 0):

On your new device:

```
Create Identity > Manual Connection > Paste code generated from other device (via "Devices > Link Device > Manual Connection")
```

This will delete the identity you just created. Awkward I know.

Here's a forum post about it. Please post and you can encourage them to change this: https://forum.getsync.com/topic/34416-change-identity/